# How JavaScript treats lines starting with a dot?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to understand the examples on [angularjs.org](http://angularjs.org). For example the following code snippet. How does this `.value` and `.factory` and `.config` work?

```
angular.module('project', ['ngRoute', 'firebase'])

.value('fbURL', 'https://angularjs-projects.firebaseio.com/')

.factory('Projects', function($firebase, fbURL) {
  return $firebase(new Firebase(fbURL)).$asArray();
})

.config(function($routeProvider) {
  ...
```

**EDIT:**

My point of not understanding the code above is the blank line after the first line and the  line starting with a dot.

Comment: It's simply one expression on multiple lines. Maybe it's easier to read for you if you put the `.value(` immediately after `'firebase'])`.

Comment: Its not clear to me what you're asking for. Maybe you're wondering why this code snippet is written "chained" or "fluent". This is just because each method returns the object its being invoked on - which is finally just `angular`. This is just a form of convenience: a developer does not need to repeat the object a method is called on.

Comment: I just made a edit. It is very hard to express a question about something which you are confused. The latest edit makes the question clearer.

Comment: It has nothing to do with dot notation - the only question is about how JS treats a line when it starts with a dot. I'll edit it, then reopen; as you might have already seen, the given answers are NOT about this - and for me, that's a sign something went wrong with the original post.

Comment: To answer your updated question: javascript ignores the line breaks and the spacing. It simply reads it as .module().value().factory.config(), but it is formatted in a human readable manner.

Comment: @JesseKernaghan: Your answer is very clear. Why don't you give that as an official answer I would immediately accept it because it caused an immediate "ahhh that easy, now I got it".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As standard [**dictates**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.3), unless there's a [**reason for ASI**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9.1) (like using postfix op, `return`, `continue`, `throw` or `break` statements), line terminators that separate language tokens are treated by JS as any other whitespace - that is, ignored. So these lines...

```
angular.module(arg1, arg2)
.value(arg3)
.controller(arg4)
.filter(arg5)
```

... are treated essentially the same as ...

```
angular.module(arg1, arg2).value(arg3).controller(arg4).filter(arg5)
```

So it's all about readability.

Comment: Thank you for making the thorough answer with reference to the official documentation. I must be fair to grant you the accepted answer because you clearly gave the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

A function in javascript can return an object that you can call a function on as well. Basically you can chain function calls. This is the same thing as, for instance, jQuery does. Let's say you have an object that has the following methods:

```
setFirstValue()
setSecondValue()
```

If you return the same object from within those methods (eg.) :

```
function setFirstValue() { do something here; return this; }
```

You can now chain these methods together:

```
object.setFirstValue().setSecondValue()
```

So .. as you can see .. the dot actually operates on the result of the previous operation - it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same as:

```
var app = angular.module('project', ['ngRoute', 'firebase'])

app.value('fbURL', 'https://angularjs-projects.firebaseio.com/')

app.factory('Projects', function($firebase, fbURL) {
  return $firebase(new Firebase(fbURL)).$asArray();
})

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  ...
```

The angular.module call returns an object, and the dot notation references the previous object returned.

Hopefully that helps you understand how the referencing of objects works in the way you've set it up.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your updated question:

Javascript ignores the line breaks and the spacing. It simply reads it as .module().value().factory.config(), but it is formatted in a human readable manner.

Comment: ... unless there's a reason for [automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9.1).

Comment: @raina77ow That is correct, +1'd your answer for being more thorough.

Answer (score 0):

`.` operates on the result of the preceding expression. For example, `angular.module('project', ['ngRoute', 'firebase'])` returns a module object, which you can call `.value` on.

Comment: There is no limit on how basic a question may be on stackoverflow but there is a rule about friendliness. I edited the question since your answer, you may want to revise your answer.